# Acquiring drop down menu option value selecting through name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am new to python and I'm trying to understand how to click on a dropdown menu where I select it through the name and not the value even though the name is shown multiple times throughout the code because each shirt has a different value where a jacket can have `14123` and a shirt has `14133` as the value.

Here is My Code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

Size=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='X-Large']/option[@value='12218866729085']").click()
```

HTML Code EX for one shirt:

```
select id="product-select" name="id" class="">

option value="12218866630781">Small</option>
option value="12218866663549">Medium</option>
option value="12218866696317">Large</option>
option value="12218866729085">X-Large</option>
```

Gives this error:

> ("//select[@name='X-Large']/option[@value ='12218866729085']").click()
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a select dropdown so you need to use select command to choose values from dropdown.  for example in java

```
  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("product-select")));

  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Medium"); //to select medium
```

instead of visible text we can use index or value, like

```
 dropdown.selectByIndex(1); //second option in dropdown as count starts from 0 in java
```

or

```
 dropdown.selectByValue("12218866663549"); //using value attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath - //select/option[text()='Medium']

Comment: still same error  >AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'